# Is there an emulator or a tool to help test mobile asp.net-mvc 4  experience on the desktop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am playing around [with asp.net-mvc 4 and jquery.mobile.mvc nuget package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975347.aspx).  I wanted to see if there is a way to simulate the iphone browser on my desktop so I can see what it would look like without having to publish to my web server?

Is there a free way to test browser experience of asp.net-mvc 4 from my desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may checkout the [User Agent Switcher plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) for Firefox.